# Access underlying database of publicly available info on website

Tags: database

Is there anyway to directly access the database underlying publicly available information. For example, on a wallpaper website I might know the database includes information on size and type because they are available filters for the site's search. Is there anyway to access that database to make my own custom search, rather than being limited to the search options provided by the search bar?

Just to be clear, I'm not talking about trying to hack into a website, I just thought that since this information is not private or restricted there may be a legitimate way to tap into it.

Comment: No, there is not, unless the site makes access to the database available. If they're intelligent, they do not.

Comment: *"Just to be clear, I'm not talking about trying to hack into a website..."* Just to be clear, in the USA the courts probably would not see it your way.

Comment: @KenWhite Why is it unintelligent to do so? Does the same database store public and private information?

Comment: The database can store whatever the site's owner sees fit to store. It's unintelligent because it defeats the entire purpose of having a web interface, and would allow anyone to just copy all of their data at will. It also gives information about the database structure (schema) that may reveal things you don't want people to know. The information *is* in fact private or restricted, because the site owner does not publicize a way to retrieve it. Just because you know I have a wallet in my pocket does not mean you have the rights to take it.

Comment: In addition, it means their site is insecure enough for someone to go in and poke around to gain access to their data.

Comment: @KenWhite (long overdue) your explanation was what I needed to understand at the time! Thank you!